# JQuery - load options after previous data is selected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reload the second select option after the 1st one is selected. I use the `.change` jQuery event but the order in which its executed is random. Is there a better event handle for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  // clearing the previous appends here.
  $('#names').empty(); 
     for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) { // assume list[i] contains different names
        var name_options = $('<option>' + list[i] + '</option>');
        $('#names').append(name_options);
     } // end of for loop

  /* I want to retrieve data when a particular option is selected. But this doesnt work*/
  $('#names').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).find(':selected').html();
  });

 /*Data for address is loaded after the previous data is selected*/
 $('#names').change(function(){
     // options for addresses are loaded here
 });

 $('#address').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).find(':selected').html();
  });
 });

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id='names' class='combobox'>
   !-- options for names go here --> 
  </select>
  <select id='address' class='combobox'>
   !-- options for addresses go here. But after the name is selected --> 
  </select>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But #address options seem to try to load before the name is even loaded. Is there a way where you can make sure #address is loaded only after #names is selected?

Comment: Try using `after` instead of `append` .

Comment: after just displays the values. But i am clearing out the previous appends in my code. I will edit it in the code here.

Comment: The change() callback is used when the value of the selection is changed.  In your question, you asked "I am trying to reload the second select option after the 1st one is loaded.", how what does "loaded" and "reloaded" mean in this context?

Comment: My bad. I meant selected.

Comment: This is the order i would want the code to run in `1) Load the #names options` `(2) Once the user selects an option from name, the second field #address gets loaded` `(3) If the user chooses to select a different name from the #names field, then #address changes accordingly`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, is this what you are looking for?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/d40qyhbb/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = [{
        value: 'Address 1',
        html: 'Name 1'
    }, {
        value: 'Address 2',
        html: 'Name 2'
    }];

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { // assume list[i] contains different names
        var name_options = $('<option value="' + list[i].value + '">' + list[i].html + '</option>');
        $('#names').append(name_options);
    } // end of for loop

    $('#names').change(function (e) {
        var theVal = $(this).val();
        $('#address').show().find('option').attr('value', theVal).html(theVal);
        $('#address').val(theVal);
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<select id='names' class='combobox'>
    <option value="">Please select name...</option>
</select>
<select id='address' class='combobox' style="display: none">
    <option value="">Waiting...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmrxtz60/) illustrating a possible answer.

The core of the function looks as follows.  When the `names` selection changes, clear any previous `address` selection values and then add new ones.

```
$('#names').change(function() {
    // options for addresses are loaded here
    $("#address").empty();
    var addresses = [ "123 Elm Street", "456 Oak Road" ];
    $.each(addresses, function(i, item) {
        var address_options = $('<option>' + item + '</option>');
        $('#address').append(address_options);
    });
});
```